# Is there a way I can find which driver file a piece of hardware is using?

Tags: linux, drivers, raspberry-pi

Is there a way I can find which driver file a piece of hardware is using?

(I want to find the driver for the Raspberry Pi3 WiFi on Raspbian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dig into [`/sys`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs). The Linux kernel exposes a lot of information about hardware and drivers there.

```
$ readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver
../../../../bus/pci/drivers/tg3
```

On this machine, the network interface `eth0` is provided by the driver `tg3`.

You can find more information about the device and the driver by exploring the directories `/sys/class/net/eth0/`, `/sys/class/net/eth0/device/` and `/sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/`.

Comment: Thanks - found `brcmfmac` - Now I just need to figure how to get it on my other system.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, some pieces of hardware require several modules, and each module in turn can be comprised of several source files in Linux. And a module can be used by several devices. `lsmod(8)` gives the full dependency tree between modules in use.